# git svn fetch/rebase error: unable to remap msys-ssl-0.9.8.dll to same address as parent -- 0x678F0000

Tags: git, perl, dll, git-svn, msysgit

I recently started getting the following git error on `git svn fetch` or `git svn rebase`, but other local git commands are working fine:

**Following is the detailed error message:**

```
C:\Git\bin\perl.exe: ** unable to remap C:\Git\bin\msys-ssl-0.9.8.dll to same address as parent -- 0x678F0000
      0 [main] perl 1300 sync_with_child: child 7092(0x324) died before initialization with status code 0x1
    567 [main] perl 1300 sync_with_child: *** child state child loading dlls
```

**Environment:**

- git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0
- OS: Windows7 64 bit
- SVN: 1.8.4-SlikSvn-1.8.4-X64
- Cygwin: I don't have cygwin installed on my machine
- Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\1E\SMSNomad\;C:\Pro
  gram Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\work\tools\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;

I have tried multiple solutions including upgrading mysysgit from 1.8.2 to latest 1.8.5.2 but no luck yet.

Comment: I've experienced that several times myself. I don't know how to fix it, but the error disappeared for me when I tried it again at later time.

Comment: @stevenl - I am getting this error since past 2 days, and multiple reboots didn't solved this issue as well. Do you remember installing/uninstalling anything which may have fixed this issue?

Comment: @stevenl - you were right! All of the sudden problem is fixed and I can fetch/rebase now :)

Comment: I suddenly encountered this problem with mysgit 1.9.4 after months of it working correctly. I updated to 2.5.3 and it started working again.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The root cause of this issue and any variants of it is two DLLs have been mapped to the same address, causing a conflict. Individual cases can be solved using *rebase*.

Msysgit 1.9.4-preview20140815 contains [a case of this issue with the libsvn_repos-1-0.dll and libneon-25.dll libraries](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/pull/245). Using the command `git svn` gives a similar error message as described in the question.

The bug report contains this workaround:

```
Rebase to free regions via: (execute as Administrator)

rebase -b 0x64000000 bin/libsvn_repos-1-0.dll
rebase -b 0x64200000 bin/libneon-25.dll
```

After this `git svn` works correctly.

Other cases should be solvable in a similar manner, choosing free addresses for the DLLs with which the issue occurs.

Comment: This worked for me, although if your environment is like mine you will just specify "libneon-25.dll" not "bin/libneon-25.dll"

Comment: Thanks heaps. Git is useless without Stackoverflow and good souls like yourself.

Comment: `rebase.exe` the `bin` directory (`bin\rebase.exe`) of msysgit/git-for-windows, should anyone wondering.

Comment: For me, the rebase command itself is giving me the same error. Any one can help?

Comment: Worked for me. Initially I was getting "failed with last error = 6" for the rebase commands. After ensuring no other processes were using the DLLs (killing all perl.exe processes started with SourceTree) the commands worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Not the best answer, but a reboot fixed it for me.

Seems related to [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/msysgit/VSStoDvvuq0/5V1PVceyE6sJ), so probably address-space related.

Comment: Appreciated your response! Unfortunately even multiple reboots didn't solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem with git 1.9.4-preview20140815 on Windows Server 2008 R2. Restarts didn't help.

I have downgraded git to version 1.8.1.2-preview20130201 and it solved a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to uninstall mysysgit and re-install it. For my case this resolved the issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and i tried restarting my machine but it didn't work. It worked when I downgraded GIT to 1.8.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, all rebasing of dll-addresses did not work for me. Now 'Git Svn' works for me again. Following steps solved the problem (Git 1.9):

1) Deinstall

2) Reboot

3) Install of most recent git version (2.7)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a system with git 1.9.5.msysgit.0.

The dll reported in the error for me was `libsvn_swig_perl-1-0`.

The exact error was:
    `C:\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** unable to remap C:\Git\bin\libsvn_swig_perl-1-0.dll to same address as parent -- 0x667B0000`

On my system the original base address of `Git\bin\libsvn_swig_perl-1-0.dll` was `0x666C0000` (`666C0000 to 66790FFF`).

I managed to solve the problem with a <kbd>rebase -b 0x667C0000 libsvn_swig_perl-1-0.dll</kbd> from within the Git\bin directory (that `0x667C0000` is my original base plus a random `0x00100000`).

---

One way to see the current base address of a dll is with <kbd>dumpbin /headers</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Restart didn't help, downgrade didn't help, but I made 
`git reset --hard` 
and it work now.

I know it was side-effect, but if someone is desperate like I was...